# Proper way for dismiss active sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In my UI, I tried to use different buttons to switch between the active sheet that should be displayed.

```
.sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
   switch item {  
      case .sheet1:
        SheetInfoViewOne()
      case .sheet2:
        SheetInfoViewTwo()        
   }
}
```

It display properly. However, I do not know the correct way to dismiss it. The user can swipe away the active sheet. It disappeared. however, I wonder if the memory will be free up? Should there be additional code for proper way of dismissing these active sheets?

Comment: First result on google: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-new-view-using-sheets

Comment: This is to dismiss with button. My question is if the user swipe away the view, how to handle the memory properly.

Comment: why you worry about memory? it would handel itself, are you facing some issue about it? Why would you be get worried about it? I did not down voted, but I think the question is wrong or need to edit

Comment: @user6539552 your question literally says "proper way to dismiss active sheet" and now you claim that's not your question. Maybe you should ask "how does memory release works in SwiftUI" instead if that's your question

Answer (score 0):

If a View is no longer in use, then it's memory is freed by iOS automatically.
So you do not have to use any "special code" to free up memory:
Just dismiss your view.

Just keep in mind, that setting .opacity to "0" does NOT free up memory, because the view is still there, you just don't see it.

Comment: also I wanted add this, as long as your View is not active in your screen or any were it can NOT be alive, that is how SwiftUI works, and when the View get killed all it private data and variable get killed as well, because they are private, that is why apple says define your State private!